# Conditionally shift values in a row while reading a csv file with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I currently have a file that I am trying to write a script for that will look in the column `fix_nam`, and if it is a non string character, e.g. time, will shift the entire row horizontally. I've tried several iterations and I can't seem to get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

cwd = os.getcwd()

file_path = os.path.join(cwd, 'test.csv')

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame, skipping the first two rows and using the third row as header
data = pd.read_csv(file_path, delimiter=' ', skiprows=2, skipinitialspace=True, index_col=False)

# Remove whitespaces from all column names
data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()

# Function to shift rows horizontally to the right if 'fix_name' has non-string characters
def shift_row(row):
    if not isinstance(row['fix_nam'], str):
        return [None] + list(row[:-1])  # Shift the row to the right
    else:
        return list(row)  # Leave the row unchanged

# Apply the shift_row function to each row in the DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame([shift_row(row) for _, row in data.iterrows()], columns=data.columns)

# Save the new file to a new CSV
output = os.path.join(cwd, 'testoutput2.csv')
data.to_csv(output, index=False)

print(data.head())
```

I've done several iterations of this and I find that my output file still remains unchanged.  What is happening currently is that my original file contains several columns and I am looking at the column `fix_nam` that will sometimes have a string but if it does not, the remaining columns are misaligned and I would like them shifted to the right.

[Data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWsYD.png):

```
Idx fix_loc fix_nam ETA Spd LL UL clr_0 clr_1 Post Center fixOvr fixInd fixInd2 FixTypes
00 183100N0682100W LALA 22:16:22 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 NY DOMES CERDA x00 x00 x00 RADAR_MON_IN/OUT_XFER/
01 183100N0682100W LALA 22:16:22 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 CERDA x0100 x04 x00 DISPLAY/OUT_XFER/AIRPORT/DCT/
02 184531N0683420W 22:18:47 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 CERDA x00 x04 x00 RADAR_MON_OUT/OUT_XFER/DCT/
03 190919N0685619W 22:22:45 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 CERDA x00 x04 x00 RADAR_MON_IN/OUT_XFER/DCT/
04 193800N0692300W 22:27:35 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 CERDA x00 x04 x00 DISPLAY/AS_FILED/OUT_XFER/DCT/
05 194748N0692411W 22:28:49 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 CERDA x00 x04 x00 RADAR_IN/OUT_XFER/DCT/
06 194748N0692411W 22:28:49 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 CERDA x00 x04 x00 RCADEV_IN/OUT_XFER/DCT/
07 230754N0694847W 22:54:09 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 CERDA x00 x4001 x00 KEEP/OUT_XFER/REPORTED/ADS_REP/
08 241119N0695649W 23:01:52 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 CERDA x00 x4001 x00 KEEP/OUT_XFER/REPORTED/ADS_REP/
09 242117N0695806W 23:03:05 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 CERDA x00 x0200 x00 MOBPST/OUT_XFER/LVCHG/
10 242637N0695847W 23:03:44 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 CERDA x00 xffffc001 x00 KEEP/OUT_XFER/REPORTED/ADS_REP/RADAR_REP/
11 244025N0700034W 23:05:25 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 CERDA CERDA x00 x04 x00 XCENTER_IN/OUT_XFER/DCT/
12 244025N0700034W 23:05:25 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 CERDA CERDA x00 x04 x00 DISPLAY/CENTER_IN/OUT_XFER/DCT/
13 245058N0700155W 23:06:42 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 90 CERDA x00 x04 x00 POSTING_IN/OUT_XFER/DCT/
14 245213N0700205W 23:06:52 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 CERDA x00 x4001 x00 KEEP/REPORTED/ADS_REP/
15 250000N0700306W 23:07:49 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 CERDA CERDA x00 x04 x00 CENTER_OUT/DCT/
16 250000N0700306W 23:07:49 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 90 x00 x04 x00 SECTOR_IN/IN_FIR/DCT/
17 250000N0700306W LAMER 23:07:49 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 90 x00 x4000 x00 DISPLAY/AS_FILED/IN_FIR/ADS_REP/
18 250000N0700306W 23:07:49 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 90 x00 x04 x00 RCADEV_OUT/IN_FIR/DCT/
19 250000N0700306W 23:07:49 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 90 x00 x04 x00 RADAR_OUT/IN_FIR/DCT/
20 250829N0700503W 23:08:53 M078 F320 F320 F320 F320 90 x00 x4001 x00 KEEP/IN_FIR/REPORTED/ADS_REP/
```

Comment: You [should](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) include your sample data as [table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) rather than a picture.

Comment: My apologies Dmitry. I was trying to but saw that indeed it did take in as a picture. I have a bit more in depth problem that I will be posting and will have the appropriate file. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dates are also going to be imported as `str` from a CSV file. You need a different approach, like using regex.

Assuming a dataframe like this one for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "fix_nam": [
            "10:00:00",
            "abc",
            "10:00:00",
            "def",
            "10:00:00",
            "10:00:00",
            "10:00:00",
        ],
        "a": [
            "xxx",
            "10:00:00",
            "xxx",
            "10:00:00",
            "xxx",
            "xxx",
            "xxx",
        ],
    },
)
```

```
    fix_nam         a
0  10:00:00       xxx
1       abc  10:00:00
2  10:00:00       xxx
3       def  10:00:00
4  10:00:00       xxx
5  10:00:00       xxx
6  10:00:00       xxx
```

You can use the following approach:

```
# assign new empty column on the end of the dataframe
df = df.assign(new_col=None)
# shift where `fix_nam` contains digits
df.loc[df["fix_nam"].str.contains(r"\d")] = df.shift(axis=1)
```

```
  fix_nam         a new_col
0    None  10:00:00     xxx
1     abc  10:00:00    None
2    None  10:00:00     xxx
3     def  10:00:00    None
4    None  10:00:00     xxx
5    None  10:00:00     xxx
6    None  10:00:00     xxx
```

Comment: Thank you e-motta. Actually, I found out as I was looking through the file that the problem is a bit more complex (to me) so I will be creating a new inquiry. Thank you so much for your assistance.